# Change color of one word in <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an html document, and want to make only one word in my `<p>` tag a different color. Is this possible without making a completely different `<p>` tag?

```html
<!-- Example -->
<p>I want to make only THIS word blue.</p>

<!-- My only solution -->
<p style="display:inline;">I want to make only </p><p style="display:inline; color:blue;">THIS</p><p style="display:inline"> word blue</p>
```

There must be a better way of doing it.

Comment: why not use `span`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `span` tag for this, it's inline by default:

```html
<h3>A much simpler solution:</h3>

<p> I only want to make only <span style="color:blue;">THIS</span>word blue </p>
```

But actually, you would do it like this normally, defining a class and applying that to the `span`:

```css
.blue_text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p> I only want to make only <span class="blue_text">THIS</span>word blue</p>
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely the correct one. But... why the inline style?

Comment: @Rounin you mean for the color blue`? Just because I wanted to stay closer to the code in the question. Of course one could define a class and apply that to the span, which would be th regular method. But if it's only used for *that* one situation, it's actually less code to write...

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a `<span>` and apply your style to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
/*example:*/ <p> I only want to make only THIS word blue </p>

/*My only solution:*/ <p style="display:inline;"> I only want to make only </p> <span style="display:inline; color:blue;">THIS</span> word blue
```

Comment: [“Try this” answers are not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212). Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem.

Comment: @Xufox, I quote from your link _Enough information to plausibly solve the OP's question. Self-explanatory code qualifies, if it satisfies this criterion._. Obviously I posted a comment to the OP's question and followed by posting this answer which is a  _"Self-explanatory code"_. And the OP is asking for a _better way_ of doing it. I could have just added an explanation to it if OP ask why using `span` instead of `p`. You could have even just edited it instead of getting aggressive to _"Self-explanatory code"_.